# is Kafka Connect Cassandra compatible with Cosmos Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, apache-kafka-connect, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I am using Kafka Connect Cassandra to read from Kafka topic and insert to Cassandra, is this compatible with Cosmos Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please view [Stream Reactor](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/index.html) which is mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/vahemesw/Kafka-Connect-Cassandra-CosmosDB).

Connect to Cosmos DB Cassandra api:

```
cqlsh <Cassandra end point provided by Cosmos DB> <Cassandra port provided by Cosmos DB> --connect-timeout=600 --request-timeout=600 -u <COSMOS DB ACCOUNT NAME> -p <COSMOS DB ACCOUNT PASSWORD>
```